# HTACCESS file rules that rewrites all domain request to a subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have a hosting account with my domain in the root and a client's domain that I'm hosting in a sub directory, both of which contain a WordPress instance. I've been using a subdomain of mine, but now we're going live with her domain, at SquareSpace. I've added some rules to the root `.htaccess` file (thank you Google/Stack Overflow) in order to rewrite incoming requests for the client's domain to the sub folder. I also removed the `.htaccess` file in the sub directory folder which holds the client WP instance.

On initial load the URL does resolve as the client's domain, but the site can't render any files, css, images, scripts, or anything and I can't access the backend of WordPress, it redirects to the root wp-admin, instead of the sub directory admin.

Below I'll list the result that I want, as well as an example of my `.htaccess` file rules. I've found a lot of *almost solutions*, but nothing has come up yet.  I'll keep searching, but thought I would reach out to the community for help.  Thank you for any input!

> mydomain.com = public_html/mywordpress

> clientdomain.com = public_html/clientsubfolder/theirwordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?clientdomain.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clientdirectory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /clientdirectory/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?clientdomain.org$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ clientdirectory/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Without deeper analysis of your implementation I would suggest that you change the order of those rule sets: you always need to implement more specialized rules further up in your configuration file. Remember that those are processed from top to bottom. Since your first block applies independent of the requested host name the second block does not result in the effect you are looking for.